# iPhone safari doesn't restrore Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, iphone, kendo-ui, safari, content-security-policy

When I open `*.docx` file from my site and press 'back', safari changes CSP to `default-srcx-apple-ql-id: 'unsafe-inline'`. I'm opening it with `window.location.href = url;`.

Site uses Angular and Kendo UI. Both use unsafe eval (can turn it off for angular with ngCsp directive, but I can't find same solution for Kendo).

I've tried to add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">` and same response header, but it didn't help.

How can I force safari to use correct CSP?